Как лучше всего разбить данный код на маленькие звенья?
В общем, есть жирные классы, которые накладывают эффекты на игрока, назовем их Applicator'ы.
Между ними дублируется код. Скажем, есть Applicator, который дает броню игроку, а есть Applicator, который броню и урон дает.
Applicator'ы имеют 2 метода Apply и Drop. Apply-выполняет над игроком логику бафа, а Drop, соответственно, возвращает все назад.
Хочется сделать так, чтобы можно было Applicator'ы собирать из маленьких кусочков + повысить общую гибкость.
Как я себе вижу новую систему:

Наложить урон и наложить броню - это отдельные звенья
Каждое звено знает, как сделать apply и drop себя
Звенья объдиняются в цепочки и вызываются в порядке в котором они были сконфигурированы для Эффекта.
Звенья передают итог своего выполнения в следующее звено цепочки. А следующее звено может заюзать эти данные, а может и нет (зависит от конкретного звена)
Между звеньями, которые накладывают на игрока эффекта, могут быть звенья, которые несут какую-то логику, например, мутировать параметры перед передачей в другую цепочку.
Думаю, что еще и Condition'ы могут быть. Типа проверка, сколько урона наложилась и если true, то выполнять другие цепочки, а если false, то закончить
В первое звено передается набор всех необходимых параметров, которые нужны для выполнения всей цепочки, а каждое звено берет лишь необходимое себе (3 словаря <string,int>,<string,string>,<string,bool>)

По идее вот как-то так, я вижу новую систему. В голове представление есть, но как +- это в коде организовать не знаю.
Например, пока не знаю, как лучше:
Должен ли каждое звено знать друг о друге и явно быть объеденено между собой. Например в Asp.Net есть middleware, которые явно другие звенья вызывают или засунуть все в коллекции и доверить последовательное выполнение другой сущности. Мне кажется, что во втором случае, если возникнет вдруг потребность в ветвлении, то могут быть проблемы с реализацией.
Визуально я вижу это, как какой-то fluent интерфейс.
Хотелось бы каких-нибудь референсов или паттернов, которые я могу взять за основу.

А вот прямо напишите в вопросе, как вы видите этот fluent интерфейс. Player1.Shield(100).Damage(50) или Player1.Shield().AttackBy(MegaBoss), вот надо бы доформулировать желаемую концепцию. Опять же, не думаю, что вы прямо в коде будете так писать, у игрока же могут быть разные случаи, зависящие от конкретной ситуации, не понимаю, как их fluent-ом можно зашивать готовыми в код. В общем, нужно больше деталей. А так на уровне абстракций - нет, не нужно чтобы разные сущности знали друг о друге. Если такое нужно, то пусть более общая сущность (игра, например) знает о них и делает что-то.

Ну типа будет жестко зашит например Effect BerserkRage к которому будет привязан сбилженная цепочка.

Мне вот еще посоветовали схематически попробовать это все нарисовать. Но опыта у меня в проектировании чего-то большого (а это можно сказать что-то большое) у меня нет =( Может кто-нибудь может подкинуть удобные инструменты, а так же схематические подходы, которые помогут  визуально это нарисовать? Или графическике примеры, как вы проектируете?

Да любую штуку возьмите, которая умеет схемы рисовать, я в draw.io рисовал схемы. Рисовать процессы однозначно полезно.
